# Sketchpy returning NameError: name 'draw' is not defined

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

So I want to draw an image and draw it with Turtle but I'm not sure how to command the Turtle to draw the image
I've tried using sketchpy after following some tutorials but it returns an error

```
from sketchpy import canvas
obj=canvas.sketch_from_image('file:///C:/Users/aryan_mukhi/Downloads/32fd871166ae8debb1f848664365963f_adobe_express.svg')

obj = draw(threshold=127)
```

```
NameError: name 'draw' is not defined
```

I've searched google but since `sketchpy` is a small library couldn't find any info on how to solve it
I checked their website apparently the draw function is part of the sketchpy package, however since it's undefined can anyone suggest any alternatives

Comment: You haven't defined `draw` anywhere in this script. Every top-level name you reference must be imported or defined somewhere. After a brief glance at the source for `sketchpy`, it looks like `sketch_from_image` objects have a `draw` method.

Comment: I think you meant to say `obj.draw(...)`.

Comment: @AryanMukhi There is a typo in their documentation. It should be `obj.draw(threshold=127)`, not `obj = draw(threshold=127)`. `obj` is a `sketch_from_image` object. `draw` is a method on that object, not a separate function. [It's now corrected on their Github](https://github.com/MRMYSTERY003/sketchpy#drawing-from-raw-image).

Comment: thanks mate but now it's give an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'